# How to change the DNS server that is being used by the services in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dns, docker-network

**UPDATE:** For some reason simply adding `dns: 1.1.1.1` to the `docker-compose.yml` under the service worked now but it didn't work when I tried it when I asked the question. **SOLVED**

My host uses PiHole as the DNS server so all docker containers inherit it. I have an app that generates a lot of DNS traffic that I don't need filtered through PiHole so I want to make that app use `1.1.1.1` DNS server.
I know there is a `dns` option that can be applied to each service but I found that it requires `network_mode` to be set to `"bridge"` which uses the default `bridge` network. However **I want my containers to use custom DNS and still be on a separate isolated network *(as the `default` network is)* and not on the default `bridge` network** *so I can potentially have multiple apps (docker-compose.yml files) using a custom DNS servers while isolated from each other (like they are normally)*. How to achieve that?

Comment: `network_mode: bridge` will usually be the default mode; in the somewhat confusing language of the Docker documentation, the Compose-provided `default` network is a "user-defined bridge network".  You should be able to set a container's `dns:` server(s) with otherwise normal or default network settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom dns for each service inside your docker-compose.yaml by adding

```
version: 2
services:
 application:
  dns:
   - <dns_server> #example: 8.8.8.8
```

Last tried myself 2 years ago using `version: 2`